# Range of $\frac{x}{1+x}$

Tags: functions

What is the range of $\frac{x}{1+x}$

**My approach :-**

$$y=\frac{x}{1+x}$$
$$y=\frac{x}{x(\frac{1}{x}+1)}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}$$
$y$ is min. If $\frac{1}{x}$ is max and $\frac{1}{x}$ is max for what value of $x$???

Comment: Your approach is incomplete. What conclusion did you draw from the final line?

Comment: From last line I want to say that y min if 1/x is max and 1/x is max if x is min and what is the min value of x for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of an invertible function is the domain of its inverse, so if the equation of the function is

$$ y=\frac{x}{1+x} $$

then the equation of its inverse is

$$ x=\frac{y}{1+y} $$

Solving the equation of the inverse for $y$ gives

$$ y=\frac{x}{1-x} $$

So the domain of the inverse is $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ which is the range of the original function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is undefined when the denominator is zero. Setting $1+x$ equal to $0$, we have that $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is undefined when $x = -1$. This means that the function has a vertical asymptote at $x = -1$.

Now check the sign on both sides of the asymptote.

Comment: Explain your answer more because sketching of graph with asymptote I don't know